# gpsd starts before device is ready

Tags: linux, gpsd

I do have a service which starts at boot and connects to `gpsd` over the `gpsd` python api. So `gpsd` will start right after boot.

If I start any service manually while the system is running, everything works fine. But when I reboot the system, `service gpsd status` will print this:

```
# service gpsd status
● gpsd.service - GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gpsd.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-07-21 08:15:47 EDT; 2min 47s ago
  Process: 5659 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/gpsd $GPSD_OPTIONS $DEVICES (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5690 (gpsd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/gpsd.service
           └─5690 /usr/sbin/gpsd /dev/ttyUSB1

Jul 21 08:15:47 nvidia-desktop systemd[1]: Starting GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon...
Jul 21 08:15:47 nvidia-desktop systemd[1]: Started GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon.
Jul 21 08:15:47 nvidia-desktop gpsd[5690]: gpsd:ERROR: SER: device open of /dev/ttyUSB1 failed: No such file or directory - retrying read-only
Jul 21 08:15:47 nvidia-desktop gpsd[5690]: gpsd:ERROR: SER: read-only device open of /dev/ttyUSB1 failed: No such file or directory
Jul 21 08:15:47 nvidia-desktop gpsd[5690]: gpsd:ERROR: /dev/ttyUSB1: device activation failed.
Jul 21 08:15:47 nvidia-desktop gpsd[5690]: gpsd:ERROR: /dev/ttyUSB1: activation failed, freeing device
```

`gpsd` just does not work.

My guess is that the `gpsd`-daemon is trying to open `/dev/ttyUSB1` before the kernel was able to create that device an then end up in error state.

What could I do to make it run in a clean way?

EDIT: My current work around is a sleep in the `gpsd` client script.

Answer (score 1):

> What could I do to make it run in a clean way?

Make `gpsd` service wait for `/dev/ttyUSB1`.

Edit the service: `systemctl edit gpsd.service` and I think it should do it:

```
[Unit]
BindsTo=dev-ttyUSB1.device
# or maybe also
After=dev-ttyUSB1.device
```

A really "clean" way to match exactly your device would be to write udev rule to match your device to create a special `/dev/your_device` dev entry and then wait and open specifically that device in your systemd service.

Comment: I already knew those lines, but the thing is gpsd just starts, when a client tries to connect to the gpsd socket, i.e. adding those lines to the service-file of gpsd brings nothing (this is just a guess, correct me if I am wrong). But if you add those lines to the service-file of the service which is accesing the socket, then everything works fine. You made me feel sure that I am on the right path, so thanks.

Comment: Good for you! Nee, I won't edit cause I don't know what to edit ; / `which is accesing the socket` Shouldn't that one wait for gpsd.socket?